# How to add the content of two files with Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

Hello there I have two files in CSV format before processing I need to have the content of the two in a single file. 
I do this in ms-dos like this

```
d:\project\>copy file?.csv file3

File1.csv

File2.csv

1 archivo(s) copiado(s).
```

then

```
rename file3 file.csv
```

but I need to do this in Ruby, the files have only text in tabulated format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because of wildcards this is more easily done at the command-line than it is in Ruby. Why not stick with the easy way?

Answer (score 3):

Run this from your project folder or change "file.csv" etc. with full paths.

```
 File.open("file.csv", "w") do |f|
   f.puts(File.read("File1.csv"), File.read("File2.csv"))
 end
```